# Delay in outbound & inbound calls for ip phones

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, elastix

I have an issue with outgoing calls and inbound calls on elastix  2.6 
 some time i can make calls from ipphoe but its take more than  10 to 25 seconds  Or cannot make calls
Incoming
 Some time phone is ringing no voice or delay  but some time its okay but take too long time for call routing

Elastix  Version 2.4.0
asterix   11.13
Freepbx    2.11.0

**CLI Output**

*-- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:21] GotoIf("SIP/143-00000090", "0?customtrunk") in new stack

```
-- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:22] Dial("SIP/143-00000090", "DAHDI/g0/0558726480,300,") in new stack
```

-- Called DAHDI/g0/0558726480

-- DAHDI/1-1 answered SIP/143-00000090

-- 0x2abb7c05aa20 -- Probation passed - setting RTP source address to 172.14.5.203:58064

```
-- Remote UNIX connection

-- Remote UNIX connection disconnected*
```

"

---

Then after 20 second line is connected some time not conecting

**Live Log 
tail -f full   output**

new stack
[2016-07-03 17:27:01] VERBOSE[5360][C-00000060] pbx.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:21] GotoIf("SIP/143-00000091", "0?customtrunk") in new stack

[2016-07-03 17:27:01] VERBOSE[5360][C-00000060] pbx.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-dialout-trunk:22] Dial("SIP/143-00000091", "DAHDI/g0/0558726480,300,") in new stack

[2016-07-03 17:27:01] VERBOSE[5360][C-00000060] app_dial.c:     -- Called DAHDI/g0/0558726480

[2016-07-03 17:27:06] VERBOSE[5360][C-00000060] app_dial.c:     -- DAHDI/1-1 answered SIP/143-00000091

Comment: You may need to up the verbosity or turn debugging on in order to track this one down. Nothing here really seems out of the ordinary. What do the status of the DAHDI interfaces look like?

Comment: @MattW , Thank you, Sorry for delay response ,  Issue already solved, issue not in our configration , Its trunk line provider issue  ...